# Blue underline and responsive image

Tags: html, css

I'm a newbie at coding and I have some questions. I hope someone can help me figure out what I did wrong. 
I have an image under a text. When the browser it's 100 % width it looks like it should be. When I resize the browser in order to see if it's responsive, the image don't move the same time with text and it stay on the middle of the page. The text it's fully responsive, everything looks just fine, but this image it's driving me crazy. What can I do to see the image under the text when I resize the browser ?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Alco - Blog</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/webflow.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/alcotemplate.webflow.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.4.7/webfont.js"></script>
  <script>
    WebFont.load({
      google: {
        families: ["Montserrat:400,700","Lato:100,100italic,300,300italic,400,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic"]
      }
    });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://y7v4p6k4.ssl.hwcdn.net/placeholder/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/webclip-slate.png">
</head>
<body>
  <header class="navbar">
    <div class="w-container">
      <div class="w-row">
        <div class="w-col w-col-4 w-clearfix">
          <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="53a187e6c2e6cb0d0ecbc4a3_logo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="w-col w-col-8 nav-column"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a><a class="nav-link" href="#page-nav-share">About</a><a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a><a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section class="w-container">
    <h4>Blog</h4>
      <img class="image" src="images/Untitled-1.png" alt="53a1bc1164a4f9aa1001d86e_Untitled-1.png">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget quam orci.</p>
  </section>
  <div class="w-container container">
     <div class="blog">
        <div class="border">
          <img class="scale-with-grid" src="images/blogpost.png" />
             <h5><a href="blog-post.html">Neque porro quisquam est qui lorem ipsum.</a></h5>
    <h3>Our Team</h3>
    <img class="image" src="images/Untitled-1.png" alt="53a1bc1164a4f9aa1001d86e_Untitled-1.png">
    <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto</p>
  </div>
  <div class="section grey footer"></div>
  <img src="images/footer.png" alt="53a425b2eaa4a69a21bd719e_footer.png">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/webflow.js"></script>
  <!--[if lte IE 9]><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/placeholders/3.0.2/placeholders.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
</body>
</html>
```

Would be highly appreciated if someone can help me. 
Look forward to hear from you.

Comment: Can you give us some code (Css / Html) or perhaps a JSFiddle.. And show us what you have / what you already have tried

Comment: We really need some code to help you out...

Comment: <section class="w-container">
    <h4>Blog</h4>
    <img class="image" src="images/Untitled-1.png" alt="53a1bc1164a4f9aa1001d86e_Untitled-1.png">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget quam orci.</p>
  </section> The problem it's on the image below the <h4> Blog. I can give the whole html document from the page if someone need to see what's wrong.

Comment: If you want people to help you here, you'll have to follow some guidelines. First advice I can give you is: Instead of writing your code here, just "Edit" your question. The more details you give to people, the more help you'll get.

Comment: Add your CSS and HTML to the original question. As you can't format them in the comments section.

Comment: The HTML/CSS was uploaded to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you don't provide any code it's hard to help you out...
However, about your Text link with blue color and underline, you can change all your link visuals with css like so:

```
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: #FF0000;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: #00FF00;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: #FF00FF;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: #0000FF;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the color was changed. But still underlined.

Comment: Did you just copy my code block on your css stylesheet or you added the other modifications you wanted? I can't do everything for you...this is basic CSS. You might want to learn the basics of it. [Css Basics](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have an issue with the image when you resize the browser. If this is the case then I recommend you to add `max-width: 100%;` to an image like this - `img{max-width: 100%;}`.

And if it's related to the blue link color then you can add `a` anchor tag and then you can say `a{color:green;}` only if you want to change the link colour globally.

And if you want to remove underline from the anchors then you have to write `a{text-decoration:none;}`. This css removes the underline from all the anchors globally.

If you want to add specific css then add the specific class name or id name before anchor. example - `.specificClassName a{/*your css*/}` or `#specificID a{/*your css*/}`

For better solution please provide html markup and css please.